# How to sort products in WooCommerce WordPress JSON API

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce-rest-api

I am using [WooCommerce JSON API](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/themes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/) on my mobile app but I am having problems sorting the the product list.

This is my url `https://www.storeurl.com/wp-json/wc/v1/products` but I don't know which parameters to add to the url to sort the products  according to `price`, `reviews`, `rating` and `popularity`.

I have read the docs but I couldn't find it. Please do you know I could do this?

Answer (score 6):

You just need to append the parameters as part of the query string like so...

```
https://www.storeurl.com/wc-api/v3/products?orderby=title&order=asc
```

To take that further, you can use the "Filter" parameter, which allows you to use any WP_Query style arguments you may want to add to your request. So for example, if you wish to sort by "Price", you would do something like...

```
https://www.storeurl.com/wc-api/v3/products?filter[order]=asc&filter[orderby]=meta_value_num&filter[orderby_meta_key]=_regular_price
```

> Filter - Use WP Query arguments to modify the response; private query
>   vars require appropriate authorization.

Ref: https://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-products

Comment: Thanks for the answer  but I've actually seen that. It doesn't explain how to order by with price, reviews, popularity  or rating.

Comment: @Ozuf - I have added additional information to clarify

Comment: Thanks  but it still didn't work. The sorting remains the same.

Comment: I updated the answer for using v3 of the API instead. I guess I forgot what was available when v1 was used.

Comment: What do I need to change in the above query to get the products ordered by rating or `average_rating`?

Comment: I think that filters are no more available. What do you BA_Webimax suggest to use in case we need to use the same result but without filter?

Comment: @SamarthAgarwal I recommend that you stick with the legacy API until they get the same functionality in the new one or you write that functionality and contribute it to the project. There is little else that can be done.

Answer (score 2):

After a long search I found solution.

you need to pass query Param like below

**https://v1t.a8c.myftpupload.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products? consumer_key=ck_4fxx69xxx195565b4ffca55aca56d2f4d6e&consumer_secret=cs_3928b95d5xxxxxe1e82xx210748956&page=1&status=publish&category=130&per_page=1&orderby=price&order=asc.**

Also you can sort by below param.

**date, id, include, title, slug, modified, menu_order, price, popularity, rating**

Ex:  &orderby=popularity, &orderby=rating

if you still facing issue comment here i will help you.
Thanks

Comment: This gives an error orderby is not one of date, id, include, title, slug, menu_order.